# Can register multiple MongoClient in built-in ASP.NET Core dependency injection?

Tags: database, mongodb, asp.net-core

I want to register multiple MongoClient with different connection strings in built-in ASP.NET Core dependency injection.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What library do you use to work with mongo? And do you currently use DI with mongo?

Comment: Hi. 
I use from mongodb driver in asp .net core.
Because my data is no structure then my collection in mongodb database in dynamic type and also I use 5 mongodb databases so I need to register 5 IMongoDatabase by different connection string in built-in dependency injection in asp .net core

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a factory for creating `IMongoDatabase` and inject it instead

```
public interface IMongoFactory
{
    IMongoDatabase Create(string databaseName);
}

public class MongoFactory : IMongoFactory
{
    public IMongoDatabase Create(string databaseName)
    {
        string connectionString = "some connection string"; //replace with your value or use configuraiton

        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        return database;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    //...
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _mongoDatabase;

    public TestController(IMongoFactory mongoFactory)
    {
        _mongoDatabase = mongoFactory.Create("TheDB");
    }
    //...
}
```

Or if you just want to use a predefined set of databases you can just use enum instead of specifying `databaseName` directly or implement multiple methods in factory

```
public class MongoFactory : IMongoFactory
{
    public IMongoDatabase Create(MongoDatabaseInstance databaseInstance)
    {
        string connectionString = "some connection string"; //replace with your value or use configuraiton

        string databaseName = GetDatabaseName(databaseInstance);
        var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        var database = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
        return database;
    }

    private string GetDatabaseName(MongoDatabaseInstance databaseInstance)
    {
        switch (databaseInstance)
        {
            case MongoDatabaseInstance.TheDB:
                return "TheDB";
            case MongoDatabaseInstance.Second:
                return "Second";
            case MongoDatabaseInstance.Main:
                return "Main";
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException(nameof(databaseInstance));
        }
    }
}
```